# merge multiple select queries and add a default value

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am using multiple select to get the certificates generated by policy in the last 10 minutes. if no certificates have been issued still list the policy with default value of 0.
if there are certificates issue with the policy then show the count of certificates issued with that policy.

the policy id's are gathered with this query

```
  SELECT POLICY_ID FROM POLICY_DOMAIN_PATH_MAP_TBL
  MINUS
  SELECT POLICY_ID FROM POLICY_DOMAIN_PATH_MAP_TBL WHERE ACTION=1 AND PATH_ID IN (-4,-2)
```

then this will count the certificates generated by each policy.

```
SELECT
     "A3"."POLICY_NAME"
     count(*)
FROM
    "POLICY_TBL"               "A3",
    "CERTIFICATE_TBL"          "A2",
    "CERT_STATUS_CHECK_TBL"    "A1"
WHERE
        "A2"."POLICY_ID" = "A3"."POLICY_ID"
    AND "A2"."ISSUE_DATE" >= sysdate - 10/1440
    AND "A1"."CERT_SERIAL_NUM" = "A2"."CERT_SERIAL_NUM"
    AND "A1"."STATUS" = '0'
GROUP BY
    "A3"."POLICY_NAME"
```

the problem is this latest query only lists the policies with a certificate generated but I need to have all the policies listed in the first query. if no certificates have been issued then default to 0 if there are certificated generated then show the count.
how can I adapt the where clause so that it search for the policies id listen in the first query and adds a a default value if nothing zero results are found for that policy id.

Comment: ANSI-92 is the standard adopted to replace implicit joins *(using `,`)* with an explicit `JOIN` syntax. That's very nearly 30 years old.  Please ***stop*** using out-dated and error prone syntax *(`,`)* from the wrong century.  Doing so will help you get queries right the first time, and then be easier to debug too. *(For example, you can't forget to include `JOIN` predicates, you'd get a syntax error.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is missing in your query - I don't see join predicates for A3. It should be something like `AND A2.POLICY_ID = A3.POLICY_ID`.

Anyway you just add outer join here:

```sql
SELECT
     "A3"."POLICY_NAME"
     count("A1"."CERT_SERIAL_NUM")
FROM
    "POLICY_TBL"               "A3",
    "CERTIFICATE_TBL"          "A2",
    "CERT_STATUS_CHECK_TBL"    "A1"
WHERE
        "A3"."POLICY_ID" = ???
    AND "A3"."POLICY_ID" = "A2"."POLICY_ID"(+)
    AND "A2"."ISSUE_DATE"(+) >= sysdate - 10/1440
    AND "A1"."CERT_SERIAL_NUM"(+) = "A2"."CERT_SERIAL_NUM"
    AND "A1"."STATUS"(+) = '0'
GROUP BY
    "A3"."POLICY_NAME"
```

or in ANSI:

```sql
SELECT
     "A3"."POLICY_NAME"
     count("A1"."CERT_SERIAL_NUM")
FROM
    "POLICY_TBL"               "A3"
    left join "CERTIFICATE_TBL"          "A2"
        on "A3"."POLICY_ID" = "A2"."POLICY_ID"
        and "A2"."ISSUE_DATE" >= sysdate - 10/1440
    left join "CERT_STATUS_CHECK_TBL"    "A1"
        on "A1"."CERT_SERIAL_NUM" = "A2"."CERT_SERIAL_NUM"
        AND "A1"."STATUS" = '0'
WHERE
        "A3"."POLICY_ID" = ???
GROUP BY
    "A3"."POLICY_NAME"
```

**Update:**
Ah, you changed your query in the question. Previously it contained a predicate by policy_id. Since you don't need it, you need to join your results:

```sql
SELECT
     "A3"."POLICY_NAME"
     count("A1"."CERT_SERIAL_NUM")
FROM
    (
      SELECT POLICY_ID FROM POLICY_DOMAIN_PATH_MAP_TBL
      MINUS
      SELECT POLICY_ID FROM POLICY_DOMAIN_PATH_MAP_TBL WHERE ACTION=1 AND PATH_ID IN (-4,-2)
    ) A0
    join "POLICY_TBL"               "A3"
        on A0.POLICY_ID = "A3"."POLICY_ID"
    left join "CERTIFICATE_TBL"          "A2"
        on "A3"."POLICY_ID" = "A2"."POLICY_ID"
        and "A2"."ISSUE_DATE" >= sysdate - 10/1440
    left join "CERT_STATUS_CHECK_TBL"    "A1"
        on "A1"."CERT_SERIAL_NUM" = "A2"."CERT_SERIAL_NUM"
        AND "A1"."STATUS" = '0'
GROUP BY
    "A3"."POLICY_NAME"
```

Comment: yes something is missing as I only want to return teh policies that are listed in the first query. the normal query that only show the policies having a certifcate issue is indeed `A2.POLICY_ID = A3.POLICY_ID`

Comment: @zn553 ok, so just use the last query above

Comment: How does it only include the list of policies generated by the first query which comes from the table: `POLICY_DOMAIN_PATH_MAP_TBL`

Comment: @zn553 Ah, you changed your query in the question. Please look at the update